# Comparing input from file with input from user php

Tags: php, html

Here i am talking from the user input with the answer number and comparing it with the input from the file , although both of them are equal but it add one to false not to correct so what  is wrong with my code

```
<body>
<?php
$read = file("Questions.txt");
$Questions[] = -1;
$x = 0;
foreach($read as $line){
  $Questions[$x] = $line;
  $x++;
}

$output[] = '';
$correct = 0;
$false = 0;
$counter = 0;
$answer = $_POST['answers'];
for ($b=0;$b<7;$b++){
    $output[$b] = "";
}
for ($y = 0;$y<$x;$y++){
    $temp = $Questions[$y];
    for ($a=0;$a<strlen($temp);$a++){
        if ($temp{$a} == "~"){
            $counter++;
        }
        else {
            $output[$counter] = $output[$counter] . $temp{$a};
        }
    }

if (strcmp ($answer[0],$output[6]) == 0){
    $correct++;
}
else {
    $false++;
}
$counter = 0;
for ($u=0;$u<7;$u++){
         $output[$u] = "";
    }
}



?>
</body>
```

Comment: "although both of them are equal but it add one to false not to correct". This is barely comprehensible. Please take the time to clearly explain the problem in detail. Very simply: What value(s) were given as input? What value(s) did you expect as output? What value(s) did you actually get as output?

Comment: This is a nightmare to read ... sic `$temp{$a}`  << whats this?   What are the inputs, All I see is `$x = $y = $z != '~'` bla bla bla....

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of missing information in this. What is in the Questions.txt file? How are the answers posted?

Assuming (BIG ASSUMPTIONS HERE) the questions txt file is split into questions with an answer seperated by | on each line.

e.g.

```
>     what is 1+1?|2
>     how do you spell red|red
```

Also assuming that the answers provided by the user is posted as a comma separated list.

e.g. 
2,red

if that is the case then.....

```
<?php
$read = file("Questions.txt");
$questions = [];
$answers = [];

foreach($read as $line){
    $qa = explode('|', $line);
    $questions[] = $qa[0];
    $answers[] = $qa[1];
}

$output = [];
$correct = 0;
$false = 0;
$userAnswers = explode(',', $_POST['answers']);

foreach($userAnswers as $key => $answer){
    if($answers[$key] == $answer){
        $correct++;
        $output[] = $questions[$key].' is correct';
    }else{
        $false++;
        $output[] = $questions[$key].' is incorrect';
    }
}

print_r($output); //or whatever
?>
```

If these assumptions are not correct maybe you can use them as suggestions?